# How can I DRY up this code?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I want to iterate over the formProps object and check for the keys and set the value on the same keys onto the errors object.

```
if (!formProps.email) {
    errors.email = "Please enter an email"
}
if (!formProps.password) {
  errors.password = "Please enter a password"
}
if (!formProps.passwordConfirm) {
  formProps.passwordConfirm = "Please enter a password confirmation"
}
if (formProps.password != formProps.passwordConfirm) {
  errors.password = "Passwords must match"
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for suggestions on how to improve your code? That should be directed for the Code Review site of Stack Exchange. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This will better as sending array because you can show all errors at same time

```
var errors = [];
!formProps.email ? errors.push("Please enter an email") : null;
!formProps.password ? errors.push("Please enter a password") : null;
!formProps.passwordConfirm ? errors.push("Please enter a password confirmation") : null;
formProps.password != formProps.passwordConfirm ? errors.push("Passwords must match") : null;
if(errors.length > 0){
    return errors;
}
```